# Custom fonts of same fontFamily but of different styles in tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I want to use Poppins of different styles like thin100, medium500...but I'm not able to find it anywhere on docs to do this.

```css
 fontFamily:{
               'poppins' :'Poppins','sans-serif'
            }
this is the import stm- 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;500&display=swap');
```

I have used like this but it applies the medium500 style, I think. I do not understand how the default style is selected and how can I differentiate between these styles?

Is there something like:

```css
fontFamily:{
    poppins-100:....
    poppins-500:....
          }
```

like how we define custom colors.

For the comments provided below:

HTML file

[image: example of font weight usage]

CSS file

[image: importing of 900 poppins style]

Comment: use `font-weight: number` to change the font

Comment: When importing the font family, you only have a single font family (i.e. "Poppins") that comes with different font weights. You can simply use the [utility classes to define the different font weights](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-weight).

Comment: I did try the font weights but couldn't see much difference. Like, I had imported black700 style so writing "font-thin" in the class name does not effect it.